# How to compare a stored string variable in GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I have a variable called x in GDB which I want to compare against a string.

```
gdb $ print $x
$1 = 0x1001009b0 "hello"
```

but a comparsion with

```
if $x == "hello"
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Related for C++ strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801112/gdb-conditional-breakpoint-on-arbitrary-types | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287838/gdb-breakpoints-with-multiple-conditions-on-non-native-types

Answer (score 28):

As @tlwhitec points out: 
You could also use the built-in `$_streq(str1, str2)` function:

```
(gdb) p $_streq($x, "hello")
```

This function does not require GDB to be configured with Python support, 
which means that they are always available.

More convenient functions can be found in https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html.
Or use

```
(gdb) help function
```

to print a list of all convenience functions.

---

For older gdb's that lack the built-in `$_streq` function,
  You can define your own comparison

```
(gdb) p strcmp($x, "hello") == 0
$1 = 1
```

If you are unfortunate enough to not have the program running (executing a core file or something), you can do something to the effect of the following if your gdb is new enough to have python:

```
(gdb) py print cmp(gdb.execute("output $x", to_string=True).strip('"'), "hello") == 0
True
```

or:

```
(gdb) define strcmp
>py print cmp(gdb.execute("output $arg0", to_string=True).strip('"'), $arg1)
>end
(gdb) strcmp $x "hello"
0
```

Comment: This will work only when debugging running process, but will not if debugging core dump.

Comment: (An alternative for non-running debugging was apparently added in an edit.)

Comment: With python support you could also use the internal `$_streq(str1, str2)` function: `(gdb) p $_streq($x, "hello")` This was probably added later than this answer was posted, I can see it in gdb 7.7.