# GDB Eigen Debugging with Conditional Breakpoints Failing

Tags: c++, gdb, eigen

I'm trying to debug with GDB using conditional breakpoints on an Eigen object. For instance, I'd like to break when any values in my vector are nonzero. I would do this in GDB:

```
break cpp/File.cpp:143 if (v != 0).any()
```

However, this doesn't work. GDB gives this:

```
Could not find operator!=
```

even though this is perfectly valid syntax. Moreover, a conditional breakpoint like

```
break cpp/File.cpp:143 if v[0] != 0
```

gives this error in GDB:

```
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Couldn't get registers: No such process.
An error occurred while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Array<int, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>, 1>::operator[](long)) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
```

The code was compiled with `-O0 -g -fno-inline`. How do I debug the contents of an Eigen object?

Comment: Thanks. I'm compiling with the Eigen source, not with the library.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Just for clarification: Eigen is header-only, i.e., not compiled separately. Eric: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801112/), (sometimes) GDB seems to have problems with overloaded operators. You could try one of these alternatives:

```
if (! v.isZero())

if (! v.cwiseEqual(0).all())
```

And instead of `if v[0] != 0` you could try one of these:

```
 if (v.data()[0] != 0)

 if (v.coeff(0) != 0)
```