# GDB breakpoints with multiple conditions on non-native types

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I'm debugging a C/C++ program where I want to set a single break point with a condition depending on multiple variables.

> break foo.cpp:60 if (bar == 3 && i == 5)

This doesn't seem to work, as it stops whenever it hits foo.cpp:60 instead of whenever both of the conditions match (it doesn't even match one of the conditions). Is there an easy way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

**Edit**: bar and i are not native C types, they are strongly typed.

> break foo.cpp:60 if ((A) bar == 3 && (B) i == 5)

Comment: Take a look at the GDB documentation.  Here is a location for the _[quickStartGuide](http://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS2230/resources/gdb-intro.html#breakpoints)_.

Comment: "they are strongly typed" -- this tells us *nothing*. You need to provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if you want help.

Comment: When it incorrectly stops at line 60, what do `p bar`, `p (A) bar`, `p i`, and `p (B) i` show?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423577/how-to-compare-a-stored-string-variable-in-gdb/7424716

Answer (score 1):

Resolve your condition statement and place its result into its own BOOL variable, then set your break point statement to evaluate the single variable.  This puts the form squarely in-line with examples shown in the GDB. documentation:

eg:

```
BOOL x = FALSE;

x = ((bar == 3) && (i == 5));

(gdb)   break foo.cpp:60 if x
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work, gdb returns the error 'No symbol "operator==" in current context.' I should mention that bar and i are not native c types (they are defined strong types). Is there a form of casting I should do? i.e. if ((bar == (A) 3) && (i == (B) 5)?

Comment: @ginginsha -   Provide more information about how exactly these variables are created/typed.  Edit your original post if needed so all will see it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
(gdb) b dump_route_info if (strncmp(route->rt_key.prefix, "192.168.0.2", 15) == 0) && route->rt_key.mask == 32
```